# Totalizar columnas en unica fila con Postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x

No entiendo por que es tan dificil encontrar Documentacion y asesoria para totalizar o sumar columnas en unica fila con Postgresql, como se hace en excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> He intentado con CUBE, ROLLUP Y CROSSTAB, pero no logro terminarlo.
>   Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar. gracias.

Answer (score 2):

No se si sea exactamente lo que desees, pero puedes agregar un trigger que llene el total por fila luego de cada insert y ejecutar algo como lo siguiente:

```
select * from table
union 
select 'total' as nombre, sum(2005-1),sum(2005-2),... from table
```

Ya si el detalle de los años está en otra tabla pues se complicaría un poco más.

Comment: Ok, intentare, pero creo que mejor cambio la pregunta. este era un ejemplo.